# Customise HERE metadata pop-up

Tags: here-api

Does anyone using the HERE API know how to customise the `metadata` pop-up on maps (i.e. background colour).

The code for it is within the SDK but I cannot see where to insert the `style` modifier

Metadata is placed via this function linking ```Metadata''' to the SDK lib

```
Metadata metadata = new Metadata();
    metadata.setString("key_poi", data.toString());
    mapMarker.metadata = metadata;

MapMarker topmostMapMarker = mapMarkerList.first;
      Metadata? metadata = topmostMapMarker.metadata;
      if (metadata != null) {
        String message = metadata.getString("key_poi") ?? "No message found.";

        _showDialog("Map Marker picked", message);
        return;
      }

      _showDialog("Map Marker picked", "No metadata attached.");
    });
```

Cannot post SDK exert for copyright reasons but those who will know the answer will likely have access to/ use the SDK themselves

Thank you

Comment: Just for future reference, this refers to the HERE SDK for Flutter and the example app is from this repo: https://github.com/heremaps/here-sdk-examples/tree/master/examples/latest/navigate/flutter/map_items_app/lib

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have managed to fix.

There is a `helper method` set out in the main.dart of the example projects on github.

`Future<void> _showDialog` holds all of the data that can be edited universally.

This then affects all uses of metadata pop-up so colour change is constant for example, sure this can be worked around.

Comment: Note that the _showDialog() function is pure Flutter, there is no HERE SDK related code in it.